# Killing a launchctl process: Cassandra

Tags: macos, mac, launchctl

I used `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.cassandra.plist` and it launches Cassandra if not started already.

`ps aux | grep cassandra` tells me Cassandra is running and I kill the process, but it just keeps getting started. How can I kill the process and hold off on launchctl from starting it up again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also stop the service by `launchctl stop cassandra` and start it back up again if you want to.

Comment: In my mac, this command doesn't stop Cassandra

Answer (score 3):

I just realized I could do `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/*.plist`

just fyi: launchctl doen't really work under a tmux session